# Solr | Highlighting Return all fields that do not have match

Tags: solr, highlight

I am using solr -7.x

I am using highlighting feature like this.

Query : /search?q=australia&collection=jeep-au&wt=json&start=0&hl=on&hl.fl=title,description,keywords&hl.method=unified&hl.fragsize=0

My ask is - Out of the 3 fields I have title,description,keywords- the q might have text only belonging to one of the 3 fields. Still I want my highlighting section to always return all the 3 fields content but highlight the field that has a match.

Currently what is happening is, only the matched field has content, other 2 fields are blank.

Like below

```
highlighting: {
id1: {
title: [
"Jeep® <em>Australia</em> Official Site. Explore Our SUV Range"
],
description: [ ],
keywords: [
"Jeep® <em>Australia</em>"
]
},
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690813/solr-highlighting-does-not-work-with-multiple-fields-hl-fl-when-dynamic-field-is

Comment: hl.q
A query to use for highlighting. This parameter allows you to highlight different terms or fields than those being used to search for documents. When setting this, you might also need to set hl.qparser.The default is the value of the q parameter (already parsed).

Comment: Both the suggestions do not seem to be working in my case  /search?q=australia&collection=jeep-au&wt=json&start=0&hl=on&hl.fl=title,description,keywords&hl.method=unified&hl.fragsize=0&hl.q=Assistance&hl.qparser=edismax   title description are still blank

Comment: So what should the highlighting return for a field that doesn't have a match? Since the snippet thats extracted (from a possibly much larger set of text) is based on where the hit in the text is.

Comment: Shouldn't it return the field value as-is? The document came up in the solr results because the query matched some part of the document - not necessarily the fields  I wanted to be highlighted.

Comment: Then it'll be returned in your regular `fl` list, and not in your list of highlighted snippets. `fl=title,description,keywords` will include those fields in the regular response, while the `highlighting  section of the response is for those parts where highlighting occurs.

Comment: Okay then I need to use a combination of fl and hl.fl in that case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying the same thing. I have documents in my index. When I search, I want to the highlighting for each document to contain all of the document (with the highlighted terms enclosed between <em> and </em>.

I was able to achieve this by using the following parameters:

- hl.fl=*
- hl.preserveMulti=true

The hl.fl-Parameter specifies which fields should be returned in the highlighting of a document.

I would give that a try.